# How to create dynamic according in table using javascript or jquery

Tags: jquery, accordion

I am trying to find the creation of accordion for every row in table dynamically but am not able to find correct solution can anyone help me
[image]

I want to show data in below raaz which should be in accordion  and link for jsfiddle is 
code to save data  is

```
 function save_data() {
        $("#users tbody").append("<tr>" + "<td >" + fname.val() + "</td>" + "<td>" + email.val() + "</td>" + "<td>" + password.val() + "</td>" + "<td><a href='' class='edit'>Edit</a></td>" + "<td><span class='delete'><a href=''>Delete</a></span></td>" + "</tr>");
        dlg.dialog("close");
    }
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/e2g5njm9/ .
The popup form is not working in fiddle